# Add 5 minute comment edit rule to privilege page

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits, grace-period

Previously I asked "Is there currently any way a user can find out about the 5 minute rule before actually running into it?" I guess that was a bad question, anyway the answer is no.

My gentle suggestion: How about telling new users about the 5 minute rule when they earn the privilege [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)?

Comment: Possibly include the main points from the previous post and refute them <DISCLAIMER>I am not passively approving of deleting and reposting, this is however subtly different</DISCLAIMER>

Comment: @RichardTingle Added differentiating points for clarification.

Comment: Why is it important that users know about the rule before running into it?  Why is this an issue to begin with?  Keep in mind they can delete a comment any time, so if there's something *really* wrong they can still just delete it.

Comment: And honestly, if the previous discussion was important enough that you need to paste the entire comment string in here, you shouldn't have deleted the post.  If it isn't important, then you should just link to it for the 10Ker's to see and provide some highlights.

Comment: Personally I would like to see the key points brought out in quotes and refuted individually rather than just a huge comment dump in the question. I started trying to do that myself but then I lost the will to live

Comment: Yikes, alright. I'll get rid of the old comments. I didn't put them there because I want to refute them. It was because I thought they were helpful.

Comment: @RichardTingle Thanks for your help trying to clean this up, I hope my last edit simplifies everyone's lives.

Comment: Comments should be written to ask clarification, and to leave some minor notes to the poster, they should not contain any important information. If they do, then these should be edited in the question/answer. The 5 minute grace period is there to allow you to fix any mistake you'd have done whlie writing it.

Comment: More information is always a good thing, given that this requires just a few words to be added to a page I think even a second class citizen can justify this. **What downsides would this have?**, assuming the downsides are none, the upsides are small and the effort required is negligable.... perhaps its a good idea

Comment: @RichardTingle The more information to put out there the harder it is to find what's most important, and the less likely users are to want to read what's shown to them.  The information *is* out there; anyone interested in it can find tons of references to the feature on meta.  It's not a feature that's prominently displayed to the user early on *because it doesn't need to be*.  There are so many more important things we'd rather they be reading than that they can't edit comments after 5 minutes.

Comment: @Servy The question is; does this deserve to be on the privileges page. It seems more important than some of the existing stuff that's on there (no revision histories, deletions are perminant etc), as such it seems to deserve its place

Comment: @RichardTingle So far I've asked *why* it deserves this place and haven't gotten an answer.  You've stated *that* it's important enough without explaining *why* it's important enough.

Comment: @Servy What i'm saying is that only x number of things can go on a page without it being confusing. **Everything about comments isn't that important**, so all that matters is; is this more important than whats already there, we can't have a blank page saying *"none of this is important, go away"*. Frankly I'd support removing the revision history stuff in support of adding this if needs be. If you asked 1000 people if they cared about the revision history more or the edit ability more I can guess how that survey would go

Comment: @RichardTingle Whether or not the current text is important enough to be worth adding is a separate and rather unrelated issue.  Does the site benefit from this information being added or not.  So far nobody has been able to provide a single reason for why this is needed, so the benefit is nothing.  Saying, "there's some other not very useful information out there, so we should add more" is a flawed argument.  If you can't explain why this is needed, then it's apparently not.

Comment: @Servy The debate about this needs perspective, from both sides. Obviously you're on the experienced user side. But try to look at this from the perspective of a fresh new user who knows nothing about the site. It is my opinion that it would be useful.

Comment: The benefit is that users will immediately know they need to consider and review their comment carefully before hitting the Add Comment button.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott Okay, *why* would it be useful.  I've asked, and nobody has answered.  Don't tell me *that* it would be useful, *show* me *why* it's useful.  Show me a user who struggled because they didn't realize this, and the negative consequences that resulted.  (And if you want to make a change like this, show it as a pattern of behavior, rather than an isolated example.)  What are the negative consequences of not doing this.  Your own personal example doesn't really seem like a problem.  I don't see how it would have been any different were this in place.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott They should consider and review there comments carefully even if they can edit them after posting them.  And if they don't, they can still delete them, so the negative consequences the first time you come to this realization are almost nothing.

Comment: "They should consider and review there comments carefully even if they can edit them after posting them" I feel we need to keep this discussion within the context of the real world

Comment: @Servy See my answer, but better user experience of knowing about something that is going to inconvenience you (for good reasons) is a better user experience is probably the best reason

Comment: @Servy I'm sorry if you can't see the logic behind this, I can't help you much beyond what's already been said. You're entitled to your opinion.

Comment: @RichardTingle People shouldn't need to be, and generally won't, consider their comments any more if they can't edit them.  People that put little thought in them won't do so either way, people that do will either way.  I can't see people writing trash comments when they think they can edit them forever and writing amazing comments when they can.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott You're the one proposing the feature.  It's your responsibility to explain why you think it adds value rather than to just say that it's important and refuse to support your feature or explain how it's beneficial.  If you're unwilling to explain why it should be implemented it's a pretty strong indication that it shouldn't be implemented.  If you're unwilling to discuss the issue then you shouldn't be posting about it, because that's what this post is here for.

Comment: @Servy In all fairness whats being said is that the reasons have already been set out. If you disagree with them then thats fair enough

Comment: @Okuma.Scott please don't accept answers until you get official response from the team (only them can edit that page). If you like a suggestion posted in answer vote it up and comment, but here on Meta accepted answer to feature request should be the answer that "close" the request, either for good (implemented and done) or bad (request declined)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd **While I complete agree**; but my accepted answer :(

Comment: @RichardTingle 70 reps are quite good! ;-)

Comment: As I am a new user to the site, I have yet to fully grasp the intricacies and etiquette of accepting answers, my apologies.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott Meta behaves differently to the main sites, because you're not really asking a question but requesting something be done it only really makes sense to accept either "I'm from stack exhange and it will be done"or "I'm from stack exhange and it won't be done"

Answer (score 16):

As far as I can see it, all this would require is an addition in the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) of

> What are comments?
>
> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.
> They can be up-voted (but not down-voted) and flagged, but do not
> generate reputation. There's no revision history, when they are
> deleted they're gone for good **and they're only editable for 5 minutes**.

The information about them being only editable for 5 minutes seems far more important than revision histories or if deletions are permanent (still not *that* important, but more important). As such the existing level of detail supports this feature request.

#### Reasons for the inclusion of this information

- There are good reasons for the edit time being 5 minutes, however, it unquestionably inconveniences some people (e.g. correct a typo in a comment than has been replied to); knowing in advance is a better user experience than being hit by it after the event.
- Knowing in advance that you cannot edit your comments encourages people to take better care commenting in the first place
- Pragmatically; it stops people thinking it's a bug

Comment: Having this explanation added to the privilege page.  Seems so obvious now.  Should this go on the FAQ as well?

Comment: @Jamal I believe the [FAQ page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work), already has this information

Comment: Ah, it does.  My mistake.

Comment: @RichardTingle I am assuming I'll just know what an official team response will look like. Standing by.

Comment: @OkumaScott, sometimes these things are quick, sometimes slow. But yes,  your post will be edited with "status-complete" or "status-declined"

Answer (score 5):

I would go with adding another section to the [privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment):

> #### Can I edit or delete my comments?
>
> Yes, you can delete any of your comments at any time and you can edit your comment within five minutes of posting it.